# How to get feature class name using ogrinfo

Tags: postgresql, ogr2ogr, kmz, ogrinfo

I am importing kmz into postgres

> $ogrCommand = 'ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" -a_srs "EPSG:4326" PG:"host='.env("DB_HOST").' port='.env("DB_PORT").' user='.env("DB_USERNAME").' dbname='.env("DB_DATABASE").' password='.env("DB_PASSWORD").'" -append '.$absFilePath.' -nln '.$schema_table.' -sql "SELECT *,'.$proj_id.' AS project_id,\''.$dbFileName.'\' AS filename,\''.$this->generateRandomFileCode().'\' AS filecode FROM '.$fileName.'"; echo $?';

I need to get feature class name from ogrinfo filename 
currently, I am getting this using below command

`ogrinfo SampleOperationArea_v2.kmz`

> INFO: Open of SampleOperationArea_v2.kmz
>
> using driver `LIBKML' successful.
>
> 1: SampleOperationArea

I just needed `SampleOperationArea` name.